# Chekcing cell background of a merged cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a range which I am trying to iterate and store the arrays present in an array until a specific case is encountered.

The data is as follows:
[image]

I am trying to iterate from `D5:D` and store in an object with their A1 notation.

This is what I tried,

```
  var gg = Sheet_1.getRange("D5").getValue();
  Concat_rows = {};
  const COLUMN = 'D';
  const START_LINE = 5;
  const Filled_LAST_ROW = Sheet_1.getLastRow();
  var LAST_ROW ;
  //To get the last row to iterate upto
  for (var i = START_LINE; i <= Filled_LAST_ROW; i++){
    let cellcolor = Sheet_1.getRange(COLUMN+i).getBackground();
    // Trying to check with the cell color to identify upto where to get the values from
    if(cellcolor == "#c6d9f0"){
      LAST_ROW = i;
      break;
    } else {continue;}
  }
  console.log(LAST_ROW);
```

Once I get that in `D5:D` I need to just iterate over `D5:D26` then I need to pull the values and their A1 notations to store in an objet for further use

I have tried this for the above,

```
for(let h = START_LINE; h <= LAST_ROW; h++) {
    let cellValue = Sheet_1.getRange(COLUMN+h).getValue()
    if (cellValue.length >= 1) {
      Concat_rows[cellValue] = COLUMN+h;
```

The problem is that the cell `D27` is a  merged cell and I am not able to figure out how to deal with it.

Comment: Please share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output. Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Only the top left cell of a merged range holds the value displayed in the user interface, so if you want the value of `C27:D27` you could do `SpredsheetAppg.getRange('C27:D27').getValue()`. If the location of the merged  range is static the solution is straight fortwarth, just add a condition and when the loop reach get the value from the merged range instead of the cell, in other words, instead of

```
let cellValue = Sheet_1.getRange(COLUMN+h).getValue()
```

use

```
let cellValue = h === 27 
? Sheet_1.getRange('C27:D27').getValue()
: Sheet_1.getRange(COLUMN+h).getValue();
```

If the location isn't known your script needs to check the location of the merged cells but doing this on a loop it's very likely that will cause that the scripts exceeds the maximum execution time. Unfortunatelly the question doesn't include enough details to provide a specific simple way to handle this. The general advice is to use batch operations and in order of get the best possible performance use the Advanced Sheets Service instead of the Spreadsheet Service.

Comment: Thank you for looking in to it, the position is not static of the merged cell